# phpmyadmin: Failed opening required '/usr/share/php/gettext/gettext.inc'

Tags: centos, php, phpmyadmin, lighttpd

Trying to access phpmyadmin on my centos 7 server,
I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/usr/share/php/gettext/gettext.inc' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/lighttpd/phpMyAdmin/libraries/select_lang.lib.php on line 477
```

I tried to isntall php-gettext, didn't help:

```
# yum install php-gettext
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * epel: mirror.freethought-internet.co.uk
 * remi: mirror.netweaver.uk
 * remi-php55: mirror.netweaver.uk
 * remi-php56: mirror.netweaver.uk
 * remi-safe: mirror.netweaver.uk
 * webtatic: uk.repo.webtatic.com
Package php-common-5.6.40-18.el7.remi.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

I'm using php 5.6 (remi)

Any idea what's wrong? 
Maybe the phpmyadmin version is not compatible with my PHP?

Comment: If you are using the latest version of phpMyAdmin you need at least PHP 7.1.3 per the [documentation](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/require.html).

Answer (score 0):

Which version have you install ? from which repository ? how ?

> /usr/share/php/gettext/gettext.inc

This file is provided by the **php-php-gettext** package, which is a dependency of phpMyAdmin 4.4. in EPEL-7.

So you shouldn't be able to install this package, without its dependency, without using some bad hack.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this problem by creating a symbolic link in the php share directory.  This was for Ubuntu 18.04:

```
/usr/share/php# ln -s php-php-gettext gettext
```

you'll want to ensure the php-php-gettext package is installed.